# What are semantics?

Tags: html

I don't quite understand the concept of semantics.
In layman's terms, what are they?
I really find it difficult to actually grasp a simple understanding about what it is, so if anyone could just elaborate it in a way an idiot like me would comprehend it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is semantic markup, and why would I want to use that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118624/what-is-semantic-markup-and-why-would-i-want-to-use-that)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to semantic markup in HTML, then it is using tags that help make sense out of the markup. For example, a header that follows form page to page in a site would be denoted by using the `<header>` tag. The main content of the site, or the content that would change form page to page would use the `<main>` tag. A footer that is the same on every page would use `<footer>`. It makes the markup easier to read, showing various sections of the page in an easy to read format.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Semantics are tags used to describe what the text inside them means. For example, `<em>` means the the text is emphasized, with italics for most browsers, and `<code>` indicates text that is a piece of code. Of course, there are more semantic tags than this, these are a few examples.